# Keyboard pushing up my view

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I'm doing a log in screen using a constraint layout because I liked the sound of the responsiveness of the guidelines, however the problem I'm having comes when the user tries to use the edit text fields and the keyboard pops up.

Firstly I've gone through the different "Adjust" methods that go in the manifest.

- AdjustNothing - My input fields are hidden behind the keyboard.
- AdjustPan - This somewhat works where it pushed my view up so the
  user can focus on what is selected, however it's extremely laggy.
- AdjustResize- This breaks my view by pushing everything into the
  available space.

In the past when using a RelativeLayout I nested the layout in a scrollview which gave it the same effect as AdjustPan, only smoother.

However If i do the same with the constraint layout, the guidelines stretch my screen size to a massively insane size, making alot of the elements appear off the screen.

Edit: Not sure if this means anything but if I have the constraint without a parent and set the height to wrap_context it stretches and does the same affect like when it is nested in a scrollview.

Here is the XML for the affected layout.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_background"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/background"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/top_overlay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/overlay"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/top_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblWelcome"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Welcome"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/top_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/right_guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/top_guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15" />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/bottom_guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ic_server"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/top_overlay"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"

                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/input_ip"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_server"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/input_ip"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.97"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input_guideline" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_ip"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/top_overlay"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:digits="0123456789."
                android:hint="@string/input_ip"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:singleLine="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input_guideline" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ic_user"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/top_overlay"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/input_username"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_user"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/input_ip"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ic_server" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_username"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/input_ip"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:hint="@string/input_username"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:singleLine="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input_ip" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ic_password"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/top_overlay"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/input_username"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_pword"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/input_ip"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ic_user" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/input_ip"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:hint="@string/input_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input_username" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_Connect"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:background="@color/material_light_red"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="Sign In"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input_password" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_overlay"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/overlay"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_guideline" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_logo"
                android:layout_width="329dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:background="@drawable/logo"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo_guideline"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="558dp" />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/input_guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/logo_guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Having the same problem, did you find an answer yet?

Comment: No, I had to get rid of the scrollview until I find a proper work around

Comment: Ouch... I found that I had to go back to my MainActivity XML and basically change the Coordinator Layout to a Linear Layout.  That helped to an extent

Answer (score 0):

**Try using `ScrollView` > `LinearLayout` as a parent layout**

**and `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"` in `AndroidManifest`**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Tried LinearLayout and Scrollview with width = match_parent and height = wrap_content and it still does the same thing.

Comment: Still the same result unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

Only enter this line `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in AndroidManifest in your activity tag.